# Compare two tables in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am displaying data from Table1 in my template as seen below, I recently created another model called Table2 which contains data which I would like to display in my table as well.

I need to check if the `code` in Table1 exists in Table2, and if so, grab the `var1` and `var2` from Table2 and display it in my template.

Does anyone know how to do this the best way?

**Pseudocode**

```
If `code` In Table1 Exists In Table2
Get var1, var2 From Table2
```

**My template**

```
{% for data in info %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ data.created }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.publisher }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.person }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.code }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**My view**

```
def home(request):

    info = Table1.objects.all()[:20]
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', {'info':info})
```

**My models.py**

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    person = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=25, default=None)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Table1'
        unique_together = (("publisher", "person", "code"),)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.created

class Table2(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=None, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, null=True)
    var1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True)
    var2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

Answer (score 0):

views.py
    def home(request):

```
    info = Table1.objects.all()[:20]
    table_2 = Table2.objects.all()[:20]
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', {'info':info,'table_2':table_2})
```

template

```
{% for data in info %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ data.created }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.publisher }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.person }}</td>
        <td>
          {% for table_2_data in table_2 %}
             {% if data.code == table_2_data.code %}
                 {{table_2_data.var1}} {{table_2_data.var2}}
             {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Shakil, this code doesn't work properly I think. It doesn't display anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

def home(request):

```
info = Table1.objects.all()[:20]
filter_data = []
for x in info:
  if x.code != '':
  try:
        getVars = Table2.objects.filter(code = x.code)
        x.var1  = getVars.var1
        x.var2  = getVars.var2
        filter_data.append(x)
      except Exception:
        filter_data.append(X)   




return render(request, 'app/home.html', {'info':filter_data})




###html


{% for data in info %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ data.created }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.publisher }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.person }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.code }}</td>
    <td>{% if data.var1 ==  %} - {%else%} {{data.var1}} {% endif %}</td>
    <td>{% if data.var2 ==  %} - {%else%} {{data.var2}} {% endif %}</td>

</tr>
```

{% endfor %}

Comment: Hi Asim, it says invalid syntax for if x.code != ''.

Comment: Please run it again there was colon miss